# Updating old records with a trigger-on-insert for a table that uses a bulk insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have to update records that are ~28 days old: I need to remove some data from the records without actually deleting the records themselves. I have decided to do this with a trigger, like this:

```
CREATE
    FUNCTION my_table_update_old_data() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
    $$ 
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE my_table
            SET identity = NULL, comment = NULL
            WHERE
                created_at < NOW()- INTERVAL '28 DAYS';
        RETURN NEW;
        END;
    $$;

CREATE
    TRIGGER my_table_update_old_data_trigger 
    AFTER INSERT ON my_table
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_table_update_old_data();
```

This works fine (in my tests) however I have some concerns regarding the `AFTER INSERT` mechanic. The table in question, `my_table`, gets updated every hour; records are bulk inserted from another temporary table, like so (simplified):

```
INSERT INTO my_table
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
        temp.table.id 
        temp_table.identity,
        temp_table.comment
    FROM temp_table
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

**Would the trigger execute ONCE, after the bulk insert, or on EACH record insertion? Any other issues with this approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

> FOR EACH ROW
>   FOR EACH STATEMENT
>
> This specifies whether the trigger procedure should be fired once for every row affected by the trigger event, or just once per SQL statement. If neither is specified, FOR EACH STATEMENT is the default.

There is no `FOR EACH` clause in the trigger declaration, so it is `FOR EACH STATEMENT` by default.

You should add an additional condition to the `UPDATE` statement, so it won't update rows which have already been nulled:

```
        UPDATE my_table
        SET identity = NULL, comment = NULL
        WHERE
            created_at < NOW()- INTERVAL '28 DAYS'
        AND
            identity IS NOT NULL;
```